# widget container de Label

Tags: tkinter

```py
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, font


class Cuadro(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, iteracion, *args, **kwargs):
        print ("long args = ", len(args), " args = ", args)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master      
        self.iteracion = iteracion

        name1 = "etiqueta 1 cuadro {}".format(self.iteracion)
        name2 = "etiqueta 2 cuadro {}".format(self.iteracion)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text=name1, background = "yellow")               
        self.label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text=name2, background = "red")                
        self.label2.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.label1.bind("<Button-1>", self.callLabel1)
        self.label1.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.callLabel1Double)

        self.label2.bind("<Button-1>", self.callLabel2)
        self.label2.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.callLabel2Double)


    def callLabel1(self, event):
        print("CUADRO: Single click in label 1")


    def callLabel1Double(self, event):
        print("CUADRO: Double click in label 1")


    def callLabel2(self, event):
        print("CUADRO: Single click in label2")

    def callLabel2Double(self, event):
        print("CUADRO: Double click in label2")


class ContenedorCuadros1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

#        self.master = master       
#        frame = tk.Frame(master, borderwidth=5)
#        self.frame = frame
        self.frame = master
        self.frame.grid(row=10, column=0)

        self.cuadro1 = Cuadro(self.frame, 10)
        self.cuadro1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.cuadro2 = Cuadro(self.frame, 20)
        self.cuadro2.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.grid()


class   Intento1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        label1 = tk.Label(master, text= "Etiqueta superior", background = "red")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        cuadro = Cuadro(master, 1)
        cuadro.grid(row=1, column=0)

        cuadro2 = Cuadro(master, 2)
        cuadro2.grid(row=2, column=0)

        frame = tk.Frame(master, background="green", width=768, height=576)
        frame.grid(row=3, column=0)
#        contenedor = ContenedorCuadros1(frame)        ##### <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
#        contenedor.grid(row=3, column=1)              ##### <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        self.quitButton = tk.Button(master, text="quit", command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=4, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__": 

    print(sys.version)
    root = tk.Tk()

    app = Intento1(root)
    root.progID = sys.argv[0] + " --> "                  # rocoge nombre del programa
    root.title(root.progID + 'Sample application')
    root.mainloop()
```

Este ejemplo es una simplificación de un intento que estoy haciendo para creacion de una ventana que presente una serie de label (dibujos en la version definitiva)
en filas y columnas.

Pare ello he creado una clase (Cuadro) que construye el cuadro y otra (ContenerdorCuadros1) que los debe de colocar por filas y columnas.

Mi problema es que cuando uso el ContenedorCuadros1, los cuadros aparecen en la parte superior, y me desaparece parte de etiquetas ya presentadas.

Me estoy volviendo loco con pruebas, y no acabo de ver que estoy haciendo mal u omitiendo.

Se puede ver la diferencia activando las dos lineas señaladas con <<<<<<<<<

¿Me podeís echar una mano y orientarme?
Soy novato en esto así que disculpar errores obvios. :-)

Muchas gracias

Por aclarar, lo que deseo es que los nuevos cuadros aparezcan dentro del frame verde.

Comment: Tienes lo que creo que es un typo, en `tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` de la clase `Cuadro` no pasas el padre como segundo argumento, debería ser `tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)`, aunque mejor usa `super`: `super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)`. Esto ocasiona que se posicione todo en la ventana principal y no en el frame padre, con lo que solapa cosas que ya tenias en ella.

Comment: Perfecto, @FJSevilla. Tu comentario, también, me aclara muchas ideas.